# T-SQL Split string into many-to-one relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, split

I have the following SQL script:

```
DECLARE @temp table (
    ID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
    data nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (data) VALUES ('a,b,c')
INSERT INTO @temp (data) VALUES ('d,e,f')

SELECT *
FROM @temp AS T
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT *
        FROM dbo.__StringSplit(T.data, ',', T.ID)) AS S
    ON T.ID = S.RefID
```

And on after clicking !Execute, I got these:

```
Line 17 The multi-part identifier "T.data" could not be bound.
```

I have also tried the non-join version and got the same error:

```
SELECT T.ID, S.Item AS dataItem
FROM @temp AS T, dbo.__StringSplit(T.data, ',', T.ID) AS S
WHERE T.ID = S.RefID
```

...

**What I expected was that I should gets a table with IDs coming from @test.ID and each comma-separated values in @test.data gets split up into its own records and its value put into the dataItem field.**

How can I accomplish that?
Am I required to use cursors?

I've pasted the dbo.__StringSplit table-valued-function implementation at http://pastebin.com/f7dd6350f

Thanks!

Comment: you will still use the cross apply, but replace the split string function with one from the link in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL2000 you need cursors. In SQL2005/2008, you can use CROSS APPLY satement; probably like next (can't test just now):

```
SELECT T.ID, S.Item AS dataItem
FROM @temp AS T CROSS APPLY dbo.__StringSplit(T.data, ',', T.ID) AS S
```

---

**EDIT** - I found [this page on CROSS APPLY](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-cross-apply-in-sql-server-2005) and then came up with:

```
SELECT T.ID, S.Item AS dataItem
FROM @temp AS T
    CROSS APPLY
    dbo.__StringSplit(T.data, ',', T.ID) AS S
WHERE T.ID = S.RefID
```

Which solved my problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

your split string function is really slow, here is a link to make a much faster one:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html