# SQL Server table of CSV strings to table of splitted strings elements

Tags: sql-server, string, csv

I have:

```
(1, 'a,b,c,d,e')
(2, 'f,g,h,i')
```

I need a table:

```
(1, 'a')
(1, 'b')
...
(2, 'h')
(2, 'i')
```

Table of CSV strings must be splitted into table of string number - string element. I have function `split(@string, @delimiter)` but it seems to be impossible to do it using this function because it says that it is not built in function. I need some advice how I can solve my problem.

Different because function `split` returns table of elements instead of scalar value

Comment: I hate to tell you - but the poroblem starts with the fact that you do NOT have a CSV. The definition of a CSV is quite stringent in using COMMATA as field separators. ONLY. No brackets. String manipulation in TSQL is awkward. Open for some C# (which can run on the SQL Server actually)...?

Comment: You need to call it as `dbo.split` not just `split`. Assuming it is in the dbo schema,

Comment: @TomTom I imagine the brackets are denoting rows and contain multiple columns. As in the row constructor syntax.

Comment: Or dupe of this possibly http://stackoverflow.com/q/763669/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith That may well be it, but this is not a CSV then. And thus any method written to work with CSV will not work and assume they are payload.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is good here and it solved my problem, thanks for reference to this question Martin Smith